# Dozer mapping : one source to multiple destinations

Tags: java, javabeans, dozer, object-object-mapping

I am a novice to `Dozer` and I just learnt to map one source object to destination using Dozer. I have to convert the source to destinations based on condition. But how can I map one field from source as another field into multiple destinations?

is this something possible at all in `Dozer`?(if not `Dozer`, anything else support this)

source class

```
class Employee{
    @Mapping("cId") //==> this works only for Contractor mapping
    private Integer eId;

    @Mapping("managerName") //==> this works only for Manager mapping
    private String eName;

    private boolean isManager;
    // set&get methods
}
```

destination1 class

```
class Contractor{
    private Integer cId;
    private String cName;
    // set&get methods
}
```

destination2 class

```
class Manager{
    private Integer managerId;
    private String managerName;
    // set&get methods
}
```

mapping

```
Contractor contractor = new DozerBeanMapper().map(employee, Contractor.class);

Manager manager = new DozerBeanMapper().map(employee, Manager.class);
```